# Sending a dynamic reading on UDP connection using esp8266

Tags: android, udp, esp8266

I have this function to send data from esp to android

```
void sendMessage(char data[]) {
//sending data

  WiFiUDP Udp2;
  Udp2.beginPacket("192.168.0.123", 9875);
  //Serial.println("Sending data to android: ");
  Serial.println(data);
  Udp2.write(data);
  Udp2.endPacket();
  delay(1);
```

and I call this function in this form

```
sendMessage("Battery is Full");
```

But i can also send an integer by replacing it with "1". What I really want is to send an integer value which i get from analog pin and pass the data in a variable so that I can send a varying output from the analog pin.

Comment: `void sendMessage(int value)` ?

Comment: int value = 12345; sendmessage(String.valueOf(value));

Comment: hmm i'll try this one, though i know what it can do this might not be what i'm looking for. But Thanks!

Comment: @John given a try to the below answer ?

Comment: sorry i just got the hardware that I lend, there's an error : invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the gathered analog integer data to char array will fix you :

```
int data = analogRead(A0);
sendMessage((char*)String(data).c_str());
```

Comment: error : invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

Comment: cast it statically like :  sendMessage((char*)String(data).c_str());

Comment: if you use this conversion method, will it:
A: keep the raw values but split it into a array so that it can fit all bits into it(so keeping the same bit structure).
or B: convert every number in the int into a char.

since Arduino tends to use 12bit for the analogport(uno, etc), and I haven't seen one over 16 bit. this means that a analog value can be send in 2 bytes(a char is 1 byte).
this means that with a 12 bit analog port it method A would take half the amounts of bytes to send compared to method B and so would be 2 times as fast as well.

so I wonder which way it sends the int

Comment: checked it with serial write and serial print and seems to use option A.